# How to override Http class in RC6?

Tags: angular

I have `CustomHttp` class and I use it to add headers to my `get` requests:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { RequestOptionsArgs, RequestOptions, ConnectionBackend, Http, Request, Response, Headers } from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {

headers: Headers = new Headers({ 'Something': 'Something' });
options1: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });

constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend,
    defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
}

get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) {
    console.log('Custom get...');
    return super.get(url, this.options1).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        if (err.status === 404) {
            console.log('404 error');
            return Observable.throw(err);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

In RC5, I added it to my `AppModule` providers like this:

```
provide (Http, {
            useFactory: (
                backend: XHRBackend,
                defaultOptions: RequestOptions) =>
                new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions),
            deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
        })
```

But, in RC6, `provide` from `@angular/core` is deprecated and I'm having problems adding my `CustomHttp` class to `AppModule` providers. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax has change a bit, besides that it should still work the same:

```
    { provide: Http, 
        useFactory: (
            backend: XHRBackend,
            defaultOptions: RequestOptions) =>
            new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions),
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it! Now, instead of importing `provide` from `@angular/core`, you need to import `Provider`. Another thing that changed in RC6 is that you now don't need to import `ConnectionBackend` from `@angular/http` and add it to module providers. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why would you need to import `Provider`? I don't think that's the case.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, my bad. Removed it and it still works like a charm. I had it imported earlier while I was trying to fix this, so I thought it's necessary.