# Angular2 Provide to Override Class

Tags: angular, angular2-di

I created a custom Http provider to handle http errors in one place in our app.  In RC4 i used to bootstrap the app like so to achieve this:

```ts
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    provide(HttpErrorService, { useClass: HttpErrorService }),  
    provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy }),
    provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, { useValue: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES], multi: true }),
    provide(Http, {
        useFactory: (xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions, eService: HttpErrorService) => new CustomHttp(xhrBackend, requestOptions, eService),
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, HttpErrorService]
    })
]);
```

How do I do something similar now that I'm running the release version?  Can i use provide in my main app.module somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```ts
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  directives: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, routing],
  providers: [
    {provide: HttpErrorService, useClass: HttpErrorService },  
    {provide: LocationStrategy,  useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
    {provide: Http, 
        useFactory: (xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions, eService: HttpErrorService) => new CustomHttp(xhrBackend, requestOptions, eService),
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, HttpErrorService]
    }]
])
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: You answered very similar question for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286983/how-to-override-http-class-in-rc6

Comment: Thank you again!  This worked the only thing I had to change is ngModule's property is providers not provider.