# cyclic dependency error when importing service into another service

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-http

I'm trying to set default headers for my http requests using the DefaultRequestOptions class provided by Angular 2. Documentation can be found here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#override-default-request-options

I want to add a default bearer token, which gets set in one of my services, but doing so gives me the following error in my browser console:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Provider parse errors: Cannot instantiate
>   cyclic dependency! Http: in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule ; Zone:
>    ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:

Here is my **default-request-options.service.ts** file:

```
import { Injectable }                         from '@angular/core';
import { BaseRequestOptions, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { UserService }                        from './user.service';

@Injectable()
export class DefaultRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    super();

    // Set the default 'Content-Type' header
    this.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
    this.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.userService.idToken);
  }
}

export const requestOptionsProvider = { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: DefaultRequestOptions };
```

Here is the relevant code in my **app.module.ts** file:

```
import { requestOptionsProvider }         from './default-request-options.service';
import { UserService }                    from './user.service';

@NgModule({ 
    imports: [
        ...
    ],  
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],    
    providers: [        
        ...        
        requestOptionsProvider,        
        UserService
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860202/di-with-cyclic-dependency-with-custom-http-and-configservice/40860233#40860233, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225627/custom-service-in-extended-http-not-getting-injected/41226493#41226493, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286983/how-to-override-http-class-in-rc6/39287030#39287030

Comment: I am facing same issue. Have you found solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine 3 services ..

Service1, Service2, Service3

- Service1 imports Service2
- Service2 imports Service3
- Service3 imports Service1

Service1 tries to import 2, 2 tries to import 3, 3 tries to import 1 and this continues forever. This is a cyclic dependency.

Break the loop to fix it.