# How to avoid "cycle dependency" error when a service needs to import another one

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm coding an Angular front-end, in which I'd like to gather all HTTP calls to the back-end in the same service.

The failing commit is [here](https://framagit.org/ojob/je-gere/-/commit/ea60af749457c3480a3b1a9a7b48b1dff930660a) (with [just one change for it to work](https://framagit.org/ojob/je-gere/-/commit/e6c76bbc8c89cee502628aa6828360a75778a0e9)), that I summarize herebelow.

So, I've got this `BackendService` class:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';

const backendUrl = 'http://localhost:5001/api/';
const statusEndpoint = '/status';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BackendService {
  // exposed Subject of this service
  public status$ = new BehaviorSubject<BackendStatus>(defaultStatus);

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  private updateStatus(): void {
    this.get(statusEndpoint).subscribe(raw => { this.status$.next(raw); });
  }

  public get(endpoint: string): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    return this.http.get(backendUrl + endpoint);
  }

(...)
```

So far, so good. Now I'd like to have other services rely on the `BackendService.get` method, which would be the central place to take care of timeouts, error handling, and such other stuff.

Now, when I define this service in another service, like this:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { BackendService } from './backend.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(
    private backend: BackendService,  // <-- here!
  ) { }
```

Then compilation goes without error, but I get following console error:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! AuthService
    Angular 7
    UserPanelComponent_Factory user-panel.component.ts:12
    Angular 5
        getNodeInjectable
        instantiateAllDirectives
        createDirectivesInstances
        elementStart
        element
    AppComponent_Template app.component.html:4
    Angular 20
core.js:6241:19
```

Where `user-panel.component.ts` is importing `AuthService`:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { AuthService, Credentials } from '../auth.service';
import { UserService, UserDetails } from '../user.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-panel',
  templateUrl: './user-panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-panel.component.scss']
})
export class UserPanelComponent implements OnInit {
  public userDetails: UserDetails;

  constructor(
    public auth: AuthService,
    public user: UserService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // trigger refresh from local storage once the component is ready
    this.auth.initializeFromStorage();
  }

  onLogOut() {
    this.auth.logUserOut();
  }

}
```

So **question**: how can I import a service into another service?

Comments:

- I saw [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307669/cyclic-dependency-error-when-importing-service-into-another-service) about real cyclic dependencies, but here I really stripped my example down, and there are no other dependencies in my services. I also couldn't find anything close on internet.
- I feel it may be related to the content of `@Injectable`, though emptying it did not bring visible improvement.)

Comment: Please, add example to git.
In your case there is no circular dependency.



By the way, do all subscriptions in components and do not forget to unsubscribe

Comment: You should show more code. For instance how you've defined the `UserPanelComponent`. Like the previous commenter mentioned, a stackblitz reproducing your issue would be best. I can see this happening if you have the following in your `providers` array: `{ provide: BackendService, useClass: AuthService }`

Comment: Mmh, I must admit I over-simplified the example, to try to be clear; I just tried to reproduce on a minimal example, but couldn't trigger the failure. Here is the [failing commit](https://framagit.org/ojob/je-gere/-/commit/ea60af749457c3480a3b1a9a7b48b1dff930660a), sorry it's on the whole projet, but the commit diff will help showing the triggering change.

Comment: @ЮрийБезруков It would seem relevant (to me at least :-)) that the services make things easy to the components for automated start of the `Subject`. What place would you consider relevant, for a central trigger of such subscriptions?

Comment: I just clarified, by pushing a commit with the sole change that avoids the error: https://framagit.org/ojob/je-gere/-/commit/e6c76bbc8c89cee502628aa6828360a75778a0e9

Comment: I moved the subscriptions out of the service... and now, no complaint anymore! Thanks @ЮрийБезруков for the hint :-)  Once this is clear in my mind, I'll update my question, so as to capitalize for others.

Answer (score 0):

The "clasic" is use Injector to get a reference to a new BackendService

```
private backend: BackendService
constructor (injector:Injector) {
    this.backend = injector.get(BackendService);
}
```

Comment: Mmh, that alone seems not enough, I still get the same error, sight :-(