# Angular: Providing Http in AoT

Tags: angular, http, dependency-injection, aot

I'm using a custom http client that I provide for a function as a dependency for a providefactory.

```
{
  provide: TranslateLoader,
  useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
  deps: [Client, Url]
},
```

In JiT works fine but in AoT I get this error message:

> ```
> ERROR in C:/PATH/src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts (1,1): Argument of type 'Client' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Http'.
>   Property '_backend' is missing in type 'Client'.
> ```

But it shouldn't matter since it's protected and a property that wouldn't be accessed from outside, right?

What should I do? Adding those protected attributes to my Client won't fix the problem, and I don't know how to make my class extending http without breaking, since in the super call I need to pass a ConnectionBackend that I don't know how it works and how to get one.

EDIT:
I've tried with the extend method but with no success:
when extending, if I have the constructor like:

```
@Injectable()
export class Client extends Http {
constructor(private authService: AuthService,  providers: XHRBackend) {
    super(providers, null);
    this.onInit();
}
```

or like

```
@Injectable()
export class Client extends Http {
constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
        super(null, null);
        this.onInit();
    }
```

overwriting the http methots to ones that makes, for example

```
return super.get(url, this._getOptions(options)).catch((error: any) => this._handleError(error));
```

it will say:

```
zone.js:569 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'merge' of null ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'merge' of null
    at mergeOptions (http.es5.js:1767)
```

Comment: "in the super call I need to pass a ConnectionBackend that I don't know how it works and how to get one." if you add it to the constructor of your child class you will get one...

Comment: Yes, I've tried: constructor(myService: MyService) { super(null, null)}, also tried constructor(myService: MyService, providers: XHRBackend) { super(providers, null)} but the first one says I don't provide backend and the second one gives a weird "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: I've seen the maxium call stack size it's due I was overwriting the get and there calling this.get again, i changed it to super.get but it says now: Cannot read property 'merge' of null ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'merge' of null
    at mergeOptions (http.es5.js:1767)

I guess I need to provide som RequestOptions too?

Comment: Please show the `HttpLoaderFactory`. Did you add `@Injectable()` to `Client` and `Url`? Did you provide `AuthService` and `XHRBackend`?

Comment: Yes I already had the @Injectable() to all those clases. I will add in the code fragments to clarify it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a provider

```
    useFactory: (
        backend: XHRBackend,
        defaultOptions: RequestOptions) =>
        new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions),
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
```

See also [How to override Http class in RC6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286983/how-to-override-http-class-in-rc6/39287030#39287030)

Comment: I find your solution more flexible than mine. Also it seems more clear. Thanks!

Comment: I think I found something similar in the Angular source (how they provide it by default). It's a while back I investigated though this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally managed to find the solution and I will post here in case someone else needs it:
I extended Angualr's Http class like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class Client extends Http {
constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService, providers: XHRBackend) {
    super(providers, new BaseRequestOptions ());
    this.onInit();
}
```

Now it works fine in JiT and AoT.

EDIT:
With this solution I still need to import HttpModule, but I use a different class than Http, this one can handle Oauth2 tokens.